# Self Join Oracle

Tags: oracle, self-join

I have a table table1 below is how the data looks like.

Column1 is my foreign key of another table.

```
    Column1 Column2 Column3
    1       A       06/MAY/14
    1       A       05/MAY/14
    1       B       06/MAY/14
    1       B       01/JAN/00
    1       A       01/JAN/00
```

Now i want to find distinct column1 values where it meets the following condition.

1.atleast one record where column2 should be A and column3 should be (sysdate - 1)

AND

2.atleast one record where column2 should be B and column3 should be (sysdate - 1)

Meaning alteast one A and B should have their column 3 populated with (sysdate - 1)

I have written the below query, please tell if i'm doing anything wrong.

I also want to know if i'm doing the right way of joining. The table contains around 50K records and performance should be fine i guess.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1 FROM 
    TABLE1 A
    JOIN 
    TABLE1 B ON (A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN1)
    WHERE
    ((TRUNC(A.COLUMN3) - TRUNC(A.COLUMN3) = 0)
    AND TRUNC(A.COLUMN3) = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
    AND TRUNC(B.COLUMN3) = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
    AND A.COLUMN2 = 'A'
    AND B.COLUMN2 = 'B'
    AND TO_CHAR(A.COLUMN3, 'DD-MON-YY') != '01-JAN-00'
    AND TO_CHAR(B.COLUMN3, 'DD-MON-YY') != '01-JAN-00'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.column1            -- Obtain distinct from A
FROM   table1 A                      -- TableA
       join table1 B                 -- TableB
         ON A.column1 = B.column1    -- Joining them on Column1 
WHERE  A.column3 = SYSDATE - 1       -- Yesterdays data on Table A
       AND A.column2 = 'A'           -- A values
       AND B.column2 = 'B';          -- B Values
```

**Note**: No distinctness in your test case. So try with a unique key.

Comment: `AND B.column3 = SYSDATE - 1` is not needed. `A.column3 = SYSDATE - 1` should take care of that. `A` and `B` are the same table.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks a lot. Forgot

Comment: Thanks, can you also tell me why the below statement returns no rows when all the rows containing column3 as '01/JAN/00'. select distinct column1, max(column3) over (partition by column1) as stmt 
from table1 where column1 in (1)

Comment: simple... Jan 2000 is not yesterday.. You said you need only sysdate -1 (Yesterday) and dont use max over parition if you dont know what it is... Read the manual first

Comment: but i dont have any where clause stating sysdate -1 in the above query. where clause is only column1 in (1).

Comment: you dont need one such. Just use sysdate-1 and it should work. You are complicating

Comment: Okay, i understood your query, and have no issues with that... my question is different now, and why this particular query "select distinct column1, max(column3) over (partition by column1) as stmt from table1 where column1 in (1)" returns no row when my column3 has a date of "01/01/1900".

Comment: if you have a different question open another one. We are glad to answer it

Answer (score 0):

For performance-comparison one with subselects and group:

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM (
    SELECT 
        COLUMN1, 
        COUNT(COLUMN2) CNT 
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            COLUMN1,
            COLUMN2
        FROM TABLE1 
        WHERE TRUNCATE(COLUMN3) = SYSDATE - 1 AND
            (COLUMN2 = 'A' OR COLUMN2 = 'B')) 
    GOUP BY COLUMN1)
WHERE CNT = 2
```